# Add users to group based on OAuth2 Role - Microsoft Azure AD - social-auth-app-django

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, django-socialauth

I'm trying to use Django-Social-Auth to log in to Django.
I have the OAuth workflow working and I can log in, but I am not part of any groups and have no permissions.

My Azure AD app has various roles configured that are mapped to AD groups. How can I map the user's role to a Django group and in turn give permissions?

If I need to create a custom pipeline function, that is fine, but I can't find any reference to access the roles.

Thanks.